# Kernel of polynomial of endomorphism is $\varphi$-invariant

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\varphi$ be an endomorphism on a $K$-vector space $V.$  Set $U=\ker f(\varphi)$, where $f$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $K$.  Show that $U$ is a $\varphi$-invariant subspace of $V.$

This question confuses me because I'm not certain that $U$ is non-empty. For example, if $K = \mathbb{Q}$ and $\varphi$ is the identity map, wouldn't $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ contradict this claim? In that case, $U = \emptyset.$

Comment: $f(\mathrm{id}) = \mathrm{id}+\mathrm{id}+\mathrm{id}$ is the map sending $x$ to $3x$; this map has kernel $\{0\}$, not empty. And if it *were* empty, then it *would* be invariant! After all, for all $x\in\varnothing$, we have $\varphi(x)\in\varnothing$....

Comment: Yes, but the empty set doesn't contain $0$, so I didn't think it was a subspace. However, that's not really important because I was thinking about polynomials of linear maps the wrong way.

Comment: The empty set is not a subspace, true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact that $f(\varphi)\circ\varphi=\varphi\circ f(\varphi)$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!